# Filter based on column which is not in summarize "DAX"

Tags: olap-cube, ssas-2008, ssas-2012, ssas-tabular

Today I would like to generate result based on following "DAX" query but it return following error.

`evaluate
(
filter
   (
   summarize
   (
     'Date',
     'Date'[Numeric Month]
   ),
      AND ('Date'[Numeric Month] >=(YEAR(TODAY())-1)* 100 + 1,'Date'[NumericDate] <=TODAY())
   )
)`

Error:

> Query (11, 60) A single value for column 'Numeric Date' in table 'Date' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

I have tried various expect with

```
ADDCOLUMNS,SUMMARIZE
```

But nothing work for this. I just want ('Date'[Numeric Month]) in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you try to achieve here. Just want distinct Numeric Months as an output? If yes do this:

```
EVAULATE(
VALUES('Date'[Numeric Month])
)
```

Otherwise you should move your Date'[NumericDate] <=TODAY() to an iterator, so pass a FILTER as a first argument to summarize

```
evaluate
(
filter
   (
   summarize
   (
     filter('Date',
     'Date'[NumericDate] <=TODAY()
     )
     'Date'[Numeric Month]
   ),
    'Date'[Numeric Month] >=(YEAR(TODAY())-1)* 100 + 1
   )
)
```